# Calling a spring batch program in a loop with every file under a unix directory as a parameter

Tags: unix, batch-processing

I have a spring batch program which I am calling from unix script as below:

```
java -DLOG_DIR=$LOG_DIR -Dlog4j.configuration=file://$CONFIG_DIR/myLog4j.log4j.properties -classpath $CLASSPATH org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner job_config.xml myJob dataDirPath=$DATA_DIR/ pdfName=one.pdf
```

Where `job_config.xml` is the spring batch configuration file and `myJob` is the job which should run.

`dataDirPath` and `pdfName` are the two parameters passed to the job.

Now I have a directory on my unix server which contains some sub directories as well.

The base directory along with the sub directories contains pdf files along with files of other types.

I want to write a script which calls above mentioned job for all the pdfs in the base directory as well as the sub directories.

How can I achieve this in unix ?

Comment: There is no Java involvement in this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

You need to change your batch job `myJob` to retrieve all pdf files from the base directory including  your subdirectory using java.

Another option would be find all the `pdf` files under the base directory including the `sub directory` using unix

`find . -name "*.pdf"`

get the output may be as comma seperated and give this comma seperated string as a parameter to your batch job, and your `myJob` should be modified to read the new parameter and process it

Comment: Is there a way to pass the files one by one in a loop ?